# Regionality of "scarf" vs "snarf" as in "to scarf down food"

Tags: american-english, dialects

A friend asked in a group chat who uses "scarf" and who uses "snarf". Some of us had only heard one or the other.

I was reminded of the American English dialect heat maps (e.g., [LINK](https://www.businessinsider.com/american-english-dialects-maps-2018-1)), and I was curious if there were any resources to find out if these words were regional.

Thanks!

Comment: Scarf appears to be a variant of snarf, both of which are AmE slang terms.

Comment: In Britain we say "scoff", which is possibly related.

Comment: I hear both, here in the US upper Midwest, but "scarf" is probably more common, by a factor of 4 or so.  And I suspect they are used with slightly different meanings.

Comment: @WS2 - Well, in the US we scoff at Britishisms.

Comment: @HotLicks *Scoff*, to speak ridicule (we can all do that), possibly comes from the old high German *scoph*. *Scoff*, both noun and verb, which have to do with voracious eating possibly originates from *scaff*, out of South Africa (OED).

Comment: @HotLicks, I hear only "snarf" in New England.

Comment: I'm hailing from pacific NW and only knew about "scarf".

Comment: @Hachi The American Heritage Dictionary has it the other way around saying `[Probably SN(ORT) + (SC)ARF]`

Comment: @Basil - yes and apparently the term have no strong regional connotation.

Comment: Note that "scarf" and "snarf" suggest two somewhat different sounds being made during the eating.  You might scarf down a sandwich but snarf down ice cream.

Comment: And then there's "wolf down"...

Answer (score 2):

"Scarf" is [much more common per Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=snarf%2Cscarf&year_start=2000&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3), and "snarf" [may have been derived from "scarf," according to Wiktionary.](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/snarf) It seems like "snarf" was particularly popular [around 2010 but first took off in the 70s, again per Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Snarf&year_start=1970&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3).

Based on the linked charts, the etymology does not appear to have any connection to [the ThunderCats character (see Wikipedia)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snarf_(ThunderCats)) but that may be responsible for its continued use.

Curiously, it appears in [the 1981 Jargon File](http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/jargon/oldversions/jarg110.txt), an old glossary used by programmers, with the meaning:

> SNARF v. To grab, esp. a large document or file for the purpose of using it either with or without the author's permission.  See BLT.
> Variant: SNARF (IT) DOWN.  (At MIT on ITS, DDT has a command called :SNARF which grabs a job from another (inferior) DDT.)

Comment: We've long had a local sandwich chain around here named [Snarf’s](https://www.eatsnarfs.com/menu). It was certainly a normal term amongst programmers in the 80s.

Comment: The OED dates the verb from the 1950s, per [this paywalled link](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/246724).

Answer (score 0):

I have heard the phrase 'scarf down', when a person is in a hurry to eat.
Example:
Fred looks down at Jim, who is eating a sandwich. Time is running out and they are about to miss their bus. Fred looks at Jim. "Hurry up. Scarf that on down or we'll miss the bus."

Or, telling a friend you are going to eat quickly: "I'll scarf this down in no time."
This type of casual speech would only be used between friends or siblings.

I have never heard the word 'snarf'.

Hope this helps.